# convert security from v2 to v5 errors

Tags: pine-script

I tried using this code in v5:

```
eu = security("EURUSD", period, rsi(close, 6))
```

but keep getting these errors:

> line 4: Undeclared identifier 'period'
>
> line 4: Could not find function or function reference 'rsi'

Anyone knows the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [migration guideline](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html#) when you are upgrading your script.

Namespaces have been introduced in v5. `security()` is now under `request.x` and `rsi` is now under `ta.x` namespaces.

The v5 equivalent of this would be:

```
eu = request.security("EURUSD", timeframe.period, ta.rsi(close, 6), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift response @vitruvius 
when I use the above for my currency pairs I get this error response: 
Script requests too many securities: 41. The limit is 40

Is there a way to code all my currency pairs without this error pls?

Comment: No. As the error message tells you, the limit is 40.

Comment: thanks again.  so is there a way of getting the closing price of an inverse pair eg, CADAUD without using the request.security so that I dont go over the 40 limit pls. Thanks in advance

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is there a mathemtical formula to convert the closing price of a forex pair to that of its inverse pair eg closing price of AUDCAD to CADAUD pls?